# ASP.NET is System.Web.UI.Page thread safe

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I am wondering if the following code is thread safe?

Can i be be sure that `UniqueFoo` will indeed be the Unique Foo and will not be override?

```
public partial class Dummy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string UniqueFoo{ get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = int.Parse(Request["Id"]);
        UniqueFoo = SomeThreadSafeWCF.GetUniqueFoo(id);
    }
}
```

what about the following (static)

```
public partial class Dummy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static string UniqueFoo{ get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = int.Parse(Request["Id"]);
        UniqueFoo = SomeThreadSafeWCF.GetUniqueFoo(id);
    }
}
```

i later want to use `UniqueFoo` in a `[WebMethod]`

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetSomeObject(SetSomeObject obj)
{
    SomeThreadSafeWCF service = new SomeThreadSafeWCF ();
    service.SetSomeObject(UniqueFoo, obj);
}
```

**EDIT**:
I am getting `SetSomeObject` from JS and `UniqueFoo` is coming from ASP.NET
will i have any issues when NOT using the `static` in my `Dummy` class according to your answers?

Answer (score 1):

Surely your first sample is thread safe because when a request of a page post to the Web Server asp.net make new instance of your page and call page_load so if your SomeThreadSafeWCF.GetUniqueFoo() always make a unique Foo everything is thread save

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet is not thread safe because you are modifying the value of a static field. So for example if later in this page you attempt to read the value of this `UniqueFoo` field you might not get the value you expect.

The first code snippet is fine because the field is not static.

If you want to use the UniqueFoo in a WebMethod then I would recommend you to pass it to this web method when calling it.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SetSomeObject(SetSomeObject obj, string uniqueFoo)
{
    SomeThreadSafeWCF service = new SomeThreadSafeWCF ();
    service.SetSomeObject(uniqueFoo, obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Darin, regarding the WebMethod call. is it good if i still call it the way i did? i am passing the 'SetSomeObject' from JS, and the 'UniqueFoo' is coming from ASP.NET. do you see any issues with this?

Comment: Yes, I see issues with that because you are overriding the value of the static field on each request.

Comment: So with your recommendation, i need to bring 'uniqueFoo' from JS as well. right?

Comment: Exactly. You already have it calculated in your `Page_Load`. So all that's left is write it somewhere on the markup.

Comment: I don't quite understand. 'SetSomeObject' is something that i get from JS, so i should take 'uniqueFoo' from JS as well? this means that i don't need 'Page_Load' can you please share some code example?

Comment: If you need to take `uniqueFoo` from JS why did you define this `UniqueFoo` field on your code behind at all? By the way you could even further simplify this code and simply pass the `id` to the WebMethod and then call the `SomeThreadSafeWCF.GetUniqueFoo(id);` inside the WebMethod.

Comment: you are right, there is no meaning to do it from code behind and i can move all the logic to ths JS. in otherwords there is no meaning to 'Page_Load', i can remove it and do all the logic in the 'WebMethod', right?